# How do I combine dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe `df` that looks like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 810 entries, 0 to 809
Data columns (total 21 columns):
event_type      810 non-null object
datetime        810 non-null datetime64[ns]
person          810 non-null object
...
from_file       0 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), int64(2), object(16)
memory usage: 133.0+ KB
```

(There are 21 columns but only the above four I'm interested in so I've omitted them)

I want to create a second dataframe `df_b` that has two columns where one of them is a combination of `df`'s `event_type,person,from_file` columns and the other is `df`'s `datetime`. Did I explain that well?... (so two columns in `df_b` from `df`'s four but where three of the above are combined into one of `df_b`'s)

I thought of creating a new dataframe `df_b` as:

```
df_b = pandas.DataFrame({'event_type+person+from_file': [], 'datetime': []})
```

Then selecting all rows with:

```
df.loc[:, ['event_type','person','from_file','datetime']]
```

But beyond that I don't know how to achieve the remainder and I keep thinking I'm going to end up with `datetime` values that didn't correspond to the original row's `datetime` that was pulled from `df`.

So can you show me how to:

- select: `event_type`, `person`, `from_file`, `datetime` from all rows in `df`
- combine: `event_type`, `person`, `from_file` with `'+'` between the values
- and then put (`event_type+person+from_file`), `datetime` into `df_b`

?

Comment: can you show us some sample data and what exactly you want to pull and combine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop NaN values use:

```
df_clean = df.dropna(subset=['event_type', 'person', 'from_file'])
```

Concatenating string columns in Pandas is as easy as

```
df_clean['event_type+person+from_file'] = df_clean['event_type'] + '+' +
   df_clean['person'] + '+' + df_clean['from_file']
```

And then:

```
df_b = df_clean[['event_type+person+from_file', 'datetime']].copy()
```

Comment: `df` sometimes has no value in `from_file` for arbitrary rows. I think the first part of this code grabs only those rows from the selected columns where there is a corresponding value. True? If that's correct I don't need to worry about grabbing rows where there wasn't a value in the column. However, the second part gets 'datetime' from all rows regardless of whether `df['event_type']`,`df['person']`,`df['from_file']` were empty or not since `df['datetime']` is in every row of `df` so the second part results in `df_b` having rows where 'event_type+person+from_file' is NaN. Can you fix that?

Comment: The first part is false, so I think it should be fine. If `from_file` is blank but the others aren't it will simply append the blank string

Comment: I don't think I was clear... I'm only need to grab the rows from `df` where all three of those columns have values, i.e. are not empty strings/NaN. If just one doesn't have a value, then it should be ignored. The second part should only add the dates for those rows that were grabbed.

Comment: Something like: `df.loc[:, ['event_type','person','from_file'].notna()==True]`.

Comment: I added a bit, give it a shot